# VirtualBox Windows 10 Host and Ubuntu 12 Guest networking not working

Tags: networking, windows-10, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I was running this very same guest on windows 7 till last week, now i upgraded to windows 10 and the guest is not able to connect anymore.

VBOX version 5.2.18

The weird thing is that i have another ubuntu 16 guest, with the same configuration, that is working fine.

Host ipconfig /all

```
Scheda Ethernet VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Suffisso DNS specifico per connessione:
   Descrizione . . . . . . . . . . . . . : VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
   Indirizzo fisico. . . . . . . . . . . : 0A-00-27-00-00-0E
   DHCP abilitato. . . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Configurazione automatica abilitata   : Sì
   Indirizzo IPv6 locale rispetto al collegamento . : fe80::24e5:f83:fbe4:4f2f%14(Preferenziale)
   Indirizzo IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.90.90.3(Preferenziale)
   Subnet mask . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Gateway predefinito . . . . . . . . . :
   IAID DHCPv6 . . . . . . . . . . . : 403308583
   DUID Client DHCPv6. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-23-1D-15-DA-E0-D5-5E-A1-C8-12
   Server DNS . . . . . . . . . . . . .  : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                           fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                           fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS su TCP/IP . . . . . . . . . . : Attivato

Scheda Ethernet Ethernet:

   Suffisso DNS specifico per connessione:
   Descrizione . . . . . . . . . . . . . : ***
   Indirizzo fisico. . . . . . . . . . . : ***
   DHCP abilitato. . . . . . . . . . . . : Sì
   Configurazione automatica abilitata   : Sì
   Indirizzo IPv6 locale rispetto al collegamento . : ***
   Indirizzo IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.2(Preferenziale)
   Subnet mask . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease ottenuto. . . . . . . . . . . . : ***
   Scadenza lease . . . . . . . . . . .  : ***
   Gateway predefinito . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   Server DHCP . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   Server DNS . . . . . . . . . . . . .  : 192.168.1.1
   Server WINS primario . . . . . . . .  : 192.168.1.1
```

Ubuntu 16 (working) network config

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet dhcp

auto enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet static
address 10.90.90.7
network 10.90.90.0
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Ubuntu 12 (broken) network config

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 10.90.90.4
network 10.90.90.0
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

When i boot ubuntu12 i get the 60 seconds timer waiting for network config, then after boot ifconfig only shows the loopback interface.
Ubuntu 16 ifconfig shows all 3 interfaces properly.

Both the VMs are configured as follows:
Adapter1: NAT
Adapter2: Host only adapter

What can be possibly causing this?

Answer (score 1):

This has happened because i changed the network interface mac address.

Deleting `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` solved my issue.